# How to load highcharts annotations module in angular module app.module.ts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to import highcharts-annotations in angular 6 typescript module file `app.module.ts`. I tried the below code but it is showing an error

> "Could not find declaration file for module 'highcharts/module/annotations' "

But the `annotations.js` file resides in the same path and it is showing error in console

> "ERROR TypeError: chart.addAnnotation is not a function".

Has someone tried this before?

**Code:**

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

import { AnnotationsModule } from 'highcharts/modules/annotations';

import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the module in that way:

```
import * as AnnotationsModule from "highcharts/modules/annotations"
```

And initialize it:

```
AnnotationsModule(Highcharts);
```

Or use require:

```
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
```

Check the demo with [highcharts-angular official wrapper](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) which I recommend you.

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/329llv6wj1